# "Nesting" of tests with OCUnit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ocunit

Coming from Rails/Rspec, I'm used to being able to manage tests something like this:

```
setup { //stuff for all tests goes here }
tests for "foo" method
  setup { stuff specific to foo method here }
  test_foo_1 { ... }
  test_foo_2 { ... }
end
tests for "bar" method
  setup { // stuff specific to bar method here }
  test_bar_1
end
```

So there's some setup run for all the tests in the file, and then for some tests there's additional setup that only applies to those tests.

I know about the `setUp` and `tearDown` methods; the thing I'm trying to do here is factor out setup code that applies to, say, 5 out of 20 tests for this file, but is unnecessary, or even harmful, for the other 15 tests.

Is an organization like that possible in OCUnit when building for iOS? The alternative I'm looking at now is defining some additional setup methods and calling them myself by hand from the appropriate tests.

Comment: You might want to look into [Kiwi](https://github.com/allending/Kiwi), a BDD style testing framework for iOS that should be pretty familiar to those who have used RSpec.

Comment: Yeah I'm not quite ready to go there yet. :)

Comment: SenTestCase has setUp and tearDown.  I believe OCTest uses the same methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Circling back on this, there are a couple of Objective-C testing frameworks which layer on top of OCUnit/XCTest and provide an `rspec`-like test organization.  [Specta](https://github.com/specta/specta) is one, [Kiwi](https://github.com/allending/Kiwi) is another. Kiwi includes its own mocking and expectations support, whereas Specta has expectations factored out into a separate package called [Expecta](https://github.com/specta/expecta).

I'm using Kiwi for a couple of projects and it's working pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean `OCUnit` (I can't find anything called OCTest).  If that's the case, you have the `setUp` and `tearDown` methods that get inherited from `SenTestCase` (OCUnit's base class).

From this article: http://meandmark.com/blog/2012/05/introduction-to-unit-testing-with-ocunit/

The `setUp:` and `tearDown:` Methods

Two optional methods that can assist you in unit testing are `setUp:` and `tearDown:`. If you have initialization code to perform before running multiple tests, you can place that code in the `setUp:` method to remove duplicate code in your tests. The `tearDown:` method contains cleanup code. A common case of using the `tearDown:` method is to free any memory you allocated in the `setUp:` method.

`OCUnit` calls the `setUp:` method before running each test and calls the `tearDown:` method after running each test. If your unit testing class has 20 tests, `OCUnit` calls `setUp:` and `tearDown:` 20 times.

Comment: Yes, I meant `OCUnit`, duh. I tried to add clarity in the question; I know about `setUp` and `tearDown` and feel like they don't fully meet my needs.

Comment: I think you can do what you're trying to accomplish with inheritance.  The base class has the setup method for all tests.  The Foo class inherits from Base and benefits from Base's setup through [super setUp];  Foo class can also handle its own setup after it calls the setUp of Base.  You'll have more files, but that should satisfy your requirement.

Comment: Multiplying files is something I was hoping to avoid. I may give it a go.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Not yet; this area went on the back burner for a bit.